# How to correctly install scipy for python3.8.1?

Tags: python

when I use 'pip install --user scipy',it's unable to install scipy.
and feedback like this.

> Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on 
>   an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
>   Original error was: dlopen failed: library "libgfortran.so.5" not
>   found
>   ----------------------------------------    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3
>   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py
>   prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
>   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmpdhsu2ps7 Check the logs for
>   full command output.

my python vrersion
✘  ~  python                                 Python 3.8.1 (default, Dec 21 2019, 19:00:26)   [Clang 8.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang b55f2d4ebfd35bf6 on linux        Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

as an error says: "library "libgfortran.so.5" not found", did you try to install that library?

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
```